# Upgraded to Angular 16 and now unable to install Firebase: ERESOLVE error in npm

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angular16

I am unable to install firebase after i updated Angular v15 to Angular v16.

**Expected behavior:**

`npm install firebase @angular/fire`

This work with the previous version of Angular which is Angular 15.

**Actual behavior: (Angular 16)**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: morish-wilson@0.0.0

npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.2

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common

npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.5.0

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/fire

npm ERR!   @angular/fire@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3353) ([also](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3348)), you can solve this by using overrides.

```
"overrides": { 
    "@angular/fire": {
        "@angular/common": "^16.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "^16.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.1"
    }
},
```